# When does PHP set the session cookie?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, cookies

I have some difficulties maintaining session on server request and response between initial server call and ajax call.

I am sending an ajax call after the server initial load to the same domain where am using sessions in both cases

The session cookie is not being set on server load (knowing that `session_start()` is called and the session has data) and it seems that it is being set twice on first ajax call:

**Server Response of ajax call after page load**

> Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=aef6668de2af148bcc3a3bd3de71f880; expires=Tue, 08-Mar-2016 07:38:43 GMT; path=/; domain=www.somedomain.com; secure; HttpOnly
>   PHPSESSID=aef6668de2af148bcc3a3bd3de71f880; expires=Tue, 08-Mar-2016 07:38:43 GMT; path=/

What actually triggers the server to send `Set-Cookie` header setting the session in cookie on server response?

Is it the `session_start()` or setting the `$_SESSION` with a given value at server side?

I know that `session_set_cookie_params()` also has this impact but can this in anyway create 2 consecutive set calls of the session if `session_set_cookie_params()` is called with `session_start()` in the same server response ?